# How can I control moving cursor movement after entering a value in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to control which cell the cursor should or should not move to after entering a value in a particular cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try VBA.

example code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) 
Select Case Target.Address() 
Case "$A$1" 
  Range("$C$15").Select 
Case "$C$15" 
  Range("$F$9").Select 
Case "$F$9" 
  Range("$A$1").Select 
End Select 
End Sub
```